# Laravel validating space character always failed

Tags: php, validation, laravel-5.5

Trying to validate if there are only spaces in input box.

This is my validations:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator;
use App\Rules\allAreSpaces;

class StoreUser extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {

        return [
            'email' => 'required|email|max:64',
            'phone' => 'bail|required|numeric|phone_min|phone_max|unique:users|not_in:0',
            'password' => [new allAreSpaces, 'required', 'min:8', 'max:16', 'confirmed'],
            'password_confirmation' => 'required',
        ];

    }

    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'email.required'     => 'Email address cannot be empty',
            'email.email'     => 'Enter a valid Email address',
            'email.max'     => 'Email address cannot exceed 64 characters',
            'email.unique'     => 'Email already exists',


            'phone.required'     => 'Mobile number cannot be empty',
            'phone.numeric'     => 'Mobile number has to be numeric',
            'phone.phone_min'     => 'Mobile number should contain a minimum 5 characters',
            'phone.phone_max'     => 'Mobile number cannot exceed 11 characters',
            'phone.unique'     => 'Mobile number already exists',
            'phone.not_in'     => 'Enter a valid mobile number ',


            'password.required'     => 'Password cannot be empty',
            'password.min'     => 'Password should contain minimum 8 characters',
            'password.max'     => 'Password cannot exceed 16 characters',
            'password.confirmed'     => 'Password mismatch.Retry',

            'password_confirmation.required'     => 'Confirm Password cannot be empty',
        ];
    }


    public function withValidator(Validator $validator)
    {


        $email = $this->request->get( 'email' );  // Start with 

        $user = \App\User::Where('email', $email)->first();


        if($user && $user->activated == 0){

            $row = \App\User::find($user->id);
            $row->delete();

        }else{

            $validator->sometimes('email', 'unique:users', function ($input) {
                return true;
            });
        }


    }

}
```

The following is the custom rule object that i was created:

```
<?php

namespace App\Rules;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;

class allAreSpaces implements Rule
{
    /**
     * Create a new rule instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the validation rule passes.
     *
     * @param  string  $attribute
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return bool
     */
    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {

        if(strlen($value) > 0){
            if (strlen(trim($value)) == 0){
                return false;   
            }
        }
        return true;

    }

    /**
     * Get the validation error message.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function message()
    {
        return 'Password cannot contain space character alone';
    }
}
```

Initially its returning, 'Password cannot contain space character alone'. but after i type some spaces then submit it shows 'Password cannot be empty'. But i want 'Password cannot contain space character alone' if the typed characters are only spaces.

Eventhough i did use the following code, its not showing if the input has some spaces, instead it shows, 'Password cannot be empty'.

```
 public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        return false;

    }
```

i was wondering why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked the global middleware, that is ran for all routes in your application which is set in your HTTP Kernel? These might come into play:

> "By default, Laravel includes the `TrimStrings` and `ConvertEmptyStringsToNull` middleware in your application's global middleware stack. These middleware are listed in the stack by the `App\Http\Kernel` class. These middleware will automatically trim all incoming string fields on the request, as well as convert any empty string fields to `null`. This allows you to not have to worry about these normalization concerns in your routes and controllers.
>
> If you would like to disable this behavior, you may remove the two middleware from your application's middleware stack by removing them from the `$middleware` property of your `App\Http\Kernel` class."

[Laravel 5.5 Docs - Requests - Input trimming and normalization](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/requests#input-trimming-and-normalization)

This might be relevant as well, goes into some complications that can happen because of these middleware:

> "By default, Laravel includes the `TrimStrings` and `ConvertEmptyStringsToNull` middleware in your application's global middleware stack. These middleware are listed in the stack by the `App\Http\Kernel` class. Because of this, you will often need to mark your "optional" request fields as `nullable` if you do not want the validator to consider `null` values as invalid. "

[Laravel 5.5 Docs - Validation - A note on optional fields](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#a-note-on-optional-fields)

Comment: is there any way that i can remove `TrimStrings` and `ConvertEmptyStringsToNull` for a single route?

Comment: there is an `except` array for the `TrimStrings` middleware in your application space that should have `password` and `password_confirm` in it ... if that isn't helping there are other things that can be done

Comment: 'password' and 'password_confirm' are already in it. Looking for other ways.